# Send ArrayList<Float> between Activities

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have to draw a graph from the values stored in an ArrayList named "subZ" (It has 252 elements). In my main activity I store the values and then in the next activity I have to draw.

So I send it like this:

```
Intent change_screen = new Intent(MeasureScreenActivity.this, ResultScreenActivity.class);
//Send variables to another activity
change_screen.putExtra("standard_measurement",standard_measurement);
change_screen.putExtra("current_measurement",current_measurement);
change_screen.putExtra("subZ", subZ);
startActivity(change_screen);
//Effect of transition
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
finish();
```

And in the other activity I recieve it like this:

```
//Store the data passed from MeasureScreenActivity
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

//Make sure that bundle is not null
if(bundle != null) {
    standard_measurement = (String) bundle.get("standard_measurement");
    current_measurement = (int) bundle.get("current_measurement");
    subZ = (ArrayList<Float>) bundle.get("subZ");
}
```

My question is: Is well done in this way? Because the metod putExtra(String, ArrayList) does not exist really.

I know about other way that is cast the ArrayList to array:

```
Float aux[] = subZ.toArray();
```

And use the method putExtra(String, Float[]) to send in the same way than before.

I do not know which on in the best way to do this because I do not want to saturate the main thread.

Other way that I am thinking is to draw in the main activity and then send the draw to the next activity to show it. But I do not know if it is possible.

**Which one of this three options will saturate less the main thread?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergio, the answer is `putParcelableArrayListExtra()`

But there is something new in Android part of Architecture components. use LiveData https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html to keep you array in the ViewModel which can be shared through your activities.

Comment: I have tried also the option of putParcelableArrayListExtra() but it gives an error because Float not extends from Parcelabel

Comment: Finally I let it like I had, it seems not so heavhy for main thread

Comment: Sergio, Read about Architecture components, Using a ViewModel you won't have to worry about that anymore. Give it a try is not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the ArrayList with
`change_screen.putStringArrayListExtra("subZ", subZ);` instead of
`change_screen.putExtra("subZ", subZ);`

Comment: This function is to ArrayList<String> and i have ArrayList<Float>. So I would have to cast before send it and then other cast when receive it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Serializable?

```
ArrayList<Float> list = new ArrayList<>();
Intent i = new Intent(MeasureScreenActivity.this, ResultScreenActivity.class);
i.putExtra("arg_key", list);
```

Get Extra

```
ArrayList<Float> list = ( ArrayList<Float>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arg_key");
```